# How to populate a ComboBox from a Legacy dropdown result in VBA (Word)

Tags: vba, combobox, ms-word, activex, legacy

I have a *Word form* (not a userform) containing *Legacy DropDownList* (**FormField**).

I can access these using the bookmark I set for them. (Ex: For one with the bookmark "bookmark")

```
ActiveDocument.FormFields("bookmark")
```

I used the **Legacy dropdowns** instead of the **ActiveX ComboBox** because I need to change the value of other **Legacy dropdowns** using the *Result* of one another and so on.

For example :

```
If ActiveDocument.FormFields("bookmark").Result <> "whatever" Then
    Select Case ActiveDocument.FormFields("bookmark").Result
        Case "Test"
            With ActiveDocument.FormFields("bookmark2").DropDown.ListEntries
                .Clear
                .Add "Whatever string I want"
                .Add "Another string I need"
            End With
    'Let's not put them all but there is more cases than one
    End Select
End If
```

In other words, the content of the next one is dependant on the content of the previous one.

That being said, I now need to do some multi-selection on the last one of these *Dropdowns*. The thing is, I can't do multi-select with **Legacy Dropdowns** from what I've read. It is possible though using **ActiveX ComboBox**, again, from what I've read.

The problem is, the way I made my "dependant" dropdowns is that, when th user selects a value, a *Module* is called doing the above code. Unfortunately, I can't use the **ActiveX ComboBox** in these *Modules*, only in the *ThisDocument*. If I could, I would only have to change the

`ActiveDocument.FormFields("bookmark2").DropDown.ListEntries`

for

`Me.ComboBoxWhatever`,

use *AddItem* instead of *Add* and find how to do multi-selection from there. But I can't.

From what I've yet tried/read, I can't call a *Sub* method from the *ThisDocument* (which here would do the code I need using the ComboBox) after a user selects a value from a **Legacy Dropdowns**.

How can I make it so when the user selects a value from a **Legacy Dropdowns**, I can check that *Result* and populate my **ActiveX ComboBox** with the appropriate values so the user can then select multiple choice from the *ComboBox* ?

**EDIT :** Cindy Meister answers is good for any **ActiveX controls** such as ListBox and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access ActiveX controls outside of `ThisDocument` through the InlineShape or Shape object which contains it. Word manages non-Word content by "wrapping" them in a graphics object.

Here's a bit of sample code I have that demonstrates how to add an item to the end of a combobox list using a procedure in a "normal" module. Notice how it uses the `OLEFormat.Object` to get "into" the ActiveX control's properties and methods.

```
Sub AddItemToExistingCombo()
    Dim doc As word.Document
    Dim obj1 As String, oIndex As Long
    Dim of As word.OLEFormat
    Dim cb As ComboBox

    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    Set of = ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(1).OLEFormat
    'Set of = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("combobox").Range.InlineShapes(1).OLEFormat
    Set cb = of.Object
    If Not cb Is Nothing Then
        oIndex = cb.ListCount
        obj1 = "item" & oIndex + 1
        cb.AddItem obj1, oIndex
    End If
End Sub
```

Of course, using the index value of the InlineShape isn't ideal, you might want to select and bookmark it. In order to do that, go into "Design mode", select the control and insert the bookmark.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am testing your solution since a bit and it seems to work. I just have to make it work in my project now which will be simple using your solution as an example of how to ! Thanks again !